# AWS SSO Login PowerShell

Tags: aws-powershell

Due to security policy, connecting to AWS programmatically with PowerShell using an Access/Secret Key is not allowed at our organization anymore, and needs to be replaced with AWS SSO. But I didn't find any clear documentation on how to actually connect to AWS with PowerShell, using AWS SSO. On AWS official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/SSO_cmdlets.html) for PowerShell Cmdlets, I can see a cmdlet named: Close-SSOSession, which is very straight forward about what is does. but which cmdlet is used to open the session in the first place? I would expect something like: Open-SSOSession. I also need to mention, that we are not allowed to install AWS CLI V2 on our Windows servers, as only the AWS PowerShell Module is approved to use by developers.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot login via SSO with the AWS Tools for PowerShell, but the team is actively working on a solution.  Keep an eye open here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs